# LifecycleNotificationUrl in microsoft graph api ( version 1.0)

Tags: java, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using microsoft graph apis (version 1.0) in my application. I am subscribed to the change notifications of inbox of a user. But now I need to know whenever the user changed his outlook password or whenever the subscription needs to be recreated.

So I updated my graph sdk(Java) to the latest versions, which are below

```
com.microsoft.graph - 2.3.1
com.microsoft.graph - 0.2.0
```

After adding `lifecycleNotificationUrl`, I am not getting the webhooks notifications whenever the users password changed.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-lifecycle.) is the document link which i used to refer.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Dinesh, Definitely you can use the existing notificationUrl endpoint that already receives change notifications, or you can register a separate lifecycleNotificationUrl to receive subscriptionRemoved and missed lifecycle notifications in a separate endpoint. You can use tools like NGROK to validate the webhook against your code. I would test against a sample like this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoftgraph/aspnet-webhooks-rest-sample/microsoft-graph-aspnet-webhooks/

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help!

I have fixed it after adding the deleted "change type" in subscription creation.
Subscription removed or missing notifications are not triggering without "deleted" change type.

This is not mentioned in the micro-soft docs that the life-cycle notifications will be triggered only on deleted change type.

Hope this helps others who are facing this type of issue.

Thanks.